# Setter and Getter behaviors in class when using std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr

I have a class in my project that I want to add a pointer attribute. in the class's constructor, I want to declare this pointer attribute so I have used a shared_ptr

my attribute datatype is `Qhash` so to declare it:

```
 std::shared_ptr<QHash<QString, QString>> Bag = std::make_shared<QHash<QString, QString>>(QHash<QString,QString>());
```

so, How do i add setter and getter in this, my expectation is:

```
    //Getter function
    QHash<QString, QString> *RequestDisplayOptions::getBag() const {
        return Bag.get();
    }

    //Setter function
    void RequestDisplayOptions::setBag(QHash<QString, QString> *bag)
    {
        Bag =std::make_shared<QHash<QString, QString>>(*bag);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what it is you actually want to know? If it's just whether or not that code would work, then your compiler can easily answer that for you.

Comment: Don't do this. If you want to a `shared_ptr` attribute, have your setter function accept a `shared_ptr` and your getter return a `shared_ptr`. Better still, don't define any setters.

Comment: I want to know if setter and getter is created as an above code @Frank

Comment: I have to use setter and getter in this case because of the project requirement, but i agree with you in general @n.m.

Comment: It sounds like a `shared_ptr` is overkill for what you're trying to achieve. Maybe a `unique_ptr` would be more appropriate because your class (seems to) owns the object.

Comment: "Have a setter" is not a requirement. "Have a function with such-and-such signature doing this-and-that" is a requirement.

Comment: What you are doing is rather meaningless because you are not actually sharing ownership of your attribute, so `shared_ptr` serves no purpose whatsoever. Perhaps you don't want to share ownership. If this is the case, you don't need any pointers at all.

Comment: If you class is just a bag of data, don't bother with setters and getters. `struct RequestDisplayOptions { std::shared_ptr<QHash<QString, QString>> Bag; };` or `using RequestDisplayOptions = std::shared_ptr<QHash<QString, QString>>`

Comment: I want to use a shared_ptr instead of using a new keyword because of a memory leak. @n.m.

Comment: it doesn't just a bag of data only. bag attribute will be used in another operation. @Caleth

Comment: It sounds like you want `QHash<QString, QString> Bag` member. There is no memory leak, there is no `new`, there is no shared_ptr. You can take the address of that member to return a pointer to it, or you can return a reference. I still doubt your need for a getter/setter pair.

Comment: You don't need **any** pointers.